# Архитектура приложения Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, mvc, spring-security

Вопрос в большей части по архитектуре приложения. Я пишу приложения облачного хранилища. Есть 2 сущности:

1. `User` - таблица, которая хранит в себе логин, пароль (в зашифр.виде), действующий токен
2. `UserFile` - таблица, которая хранит в себе данные файла (байты, название, размер)

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String userToken;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private List<UserFile> file;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class UserFile {
    @Id
    private String fileName;
    private long fileSize;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100_000_000)
    private byte[] file;

    private long userId;

}
```

После того, как пользователь авторизовался, он может, к примеру, загрузить файл. Загрузкой файла занимается класс `UserFileService`, который обращается к `UserFileRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserFileRepository extends JpaRepository<UserFile, String> {
```

Как проходит процесс загрузки: метод загрузки принимает `MultipartFile multipartFile`, далее, используя сервис `userService`, достается текущий пользователь из `SecurityContextHolder`, после чего на основе `multipartFile` создается объект `UserFile`.

```
var user = userService.findUserByEmail(
                    SecurityContextHolder.
                            getContext().
                            getAuthentication().
                            getName()
            );
            var userFile = UserFile.builder().
                    fileName(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()).
                    fileSize(multipartFile.getSize()).
                    file(multipartFile.getBytes()).
                    userId(user.getId()).
                    build();
            userFileRepository.saveAndFlush(userFile);
```

И вот мой вопрос: как обойти проблему постоянного обращения к `SecurityContextHolder`? Я вынужден в начале любой операции (удаление/обновление/скачивание/получения списка файлов) обращаться к контексту и вынимать авторизованного пользователя, чтобы понимать с каким именно пользователем я работаю. Я бы мог добавить зависимость к  `UserFileService` (`private User user`) и инкрементировать ее, чтобы постоянно не лезть в контекст, но тогда получится ерунда по двум пунктам:

1. Для работы с `User` есть отдельный репозиторий (`UserRepository`), и вся работа с `entity User` должна проходить через него
2. Получится, что я добавил в сервисный слой зависимость от модели, что не есть хорошо

Знаю, что можно добавить объект `Principal` в контроллере, чтобы Spring автоматически инкрементировал его, а уже из него получать объект авторизации, но подумал, может есть другое решение?

Спасибо)

Comment: Вот все способы получения пользователя, если вы используете Spring Security https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security. Надо понять, что вы используете библиотеку и независимо от того, хотите вы или нет, вы должны использовать её "API". По вашему вопросу варианта три: смерится, сделать свою "обёртку" (чтобы так сильно не бросалось в глаза обращение к контексту), написать свою авторизацию (это не очень сложно). Я бы выбрал написание своей авторизации